# Difference between EitherOfDiverse vs EnsureSigned inside pallet config?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

When using this one, I get `BadOrigin` as in screenshot,

[image]

```
type ApproveOrigin = EitherOfDiverse<
        EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 3, 5>,
    >;
```

vs

and when using this one transaction successfully executed.

```
type ApproveOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
```

Can someone please tell me difference between using two of them inside pallet config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `BadOrigin` error when sigining it as `Alice` is because you're not dispatching this call via `sudo` under the `Developer` tab. This is needed by polkadot-js to correctly craft a wrapped extrinsic.

The sudo call wraps a extrinsic and the sudo call itself must be signed by the superuser in order to pass the check for `ensure_root(origin)` in the pallet.

Answer (score 1):

Both are different in which origin can call a specific function, in this case for the pallet_treasury is who can approve. [Here's an example in the pallet_treasury](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/pallet_treasury/lib.rs.html#386)

[EnsureSigned](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/struct.EnsureSigned.html) only checks that the origin that is calling this function signed the message, so in this case if `ApproveOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>` then anyone that sends a signed extrinsic could call this function.

Now [EitherOfDiverse<L,R>](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/struct.EitherOfDiverse.html) works basically like an OR gate, meaning that this function can be called by either L or R, in the example you gave it would be either a root account (`EnsureRoot<AccountId>`) or by the council collective with a proportion equal or higher than 3/5 (`pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 3, 5>`). This means that not anyone can call this function only the origin that meets either of those 2 requirements.

Edit: Even if an account is sudo account it will not work if you don't execute the extrinsic using the sudo pallet. This will send the request with a sudo origin. Here's an example.

[image]

Comment: hey @Valentin Fernandez, since `Alice` is root Account. I use Alice to approve proposal but I got `BadOrigin` issue [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LrmamPWdh6Deya0tBSCdDajz317YKsS5/view?usp=sharing). Can you please tell me how to configure so that it works properly?